# Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: XXX>>": "Comment.user" must be a "MyProfile" instance

Tags: python, django

Hello I know I have two problems here. one is a `SimpleLazyObject` issue which I can fix it in a kinda hackish way. The other is "`Comment.user`" must be a "`MyProfile`" instance which I don't know how to fix. I think somewhere in the way, things got mixed up.

```
def post(request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
        try:
            profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
            # profile = request.user.myprofile
        except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            profile = None
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        post.save()      # and save it
        comments = post.comment_set.all()
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            post_instance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            post_instance.user = request.user #this is where error is occuring, if I put request.user.id simpleLazyObject dissapears.
            post_instance.path = request.get_full_path()
            post_instance.post = post
            post_instance.save()

        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'profile' :profile,
            'comments':comments,
            'comment_form': comment_form
        }

        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

I'm not sure what it means by `Comment.user` must be `MyProfile` instance.

In my comments app, *models.py* I have

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
```

and in my accounts app, *models.py* I have

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='my_profile')
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment has `ForeignKey` to `MyProfile`, yet in the line that triggers the error you provide a `User` model.
The correct way would be:

```
my_p = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
post_instance.user = my_p
```

Note that you use:

```
MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

And not the `id` field. Although behind the scenes django does use the `id` field as the real foreign key in the database, in your code you use the object. A relational field is a descriptor where django does the magic to run a relational query.

Comment: hey . It's the relational ORM

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very confused with this right no. aren't those basically same  tihngs? I tried it like that but still gets same error....what do I need to change exactly?maybe I'm not getting it right

Comment: No they are not. The foreign key of Comments.user expects a MyProfile and not User.

Comment: you have the answer put hose two lines in the is_valid instead of the line that makes the error