# Django Not Null Constraint Failed: webapp_post.author_id

Tags: python, django

When I try to create a new post in a QuerySet, Django spews out the following error:

```
Not NULL constraint failed: webapp_post.author_id
```

Here is the views.py

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated)
def add_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.save()
                postObject = Post.objects.create(title=form.cleaned_data.get("title"), text=form.cleaned_data.get("text"), author=form.cleaned_data.get("author"))
                return redirect(post)
            except IntegrityError as e:
                print(e)
        else:
            print("Invalid form")
            print(form.errors)

    return render_to_response('webapp/startthread.html', 
                              { 'form': form,
                                "authenticated": request.user.is_authenticated() },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    up_vote = 0 # num of up votes
    down_vote = 0 #num of down votes
    vote_total = up_vote - down_vote
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=True)

    CHOICES = [
        ('Hardware and OS', 'Hardware and OS'),
        ('Desktops', 'Desktops'),
        ('Tablets', 'Tablets'),
        ('Phones', 'Phones'),
        ('Wearables', 'Wearables'),
        ('Windows', 'Windows'),
        ('Mac OS X', 'Mac OS X'),
        ('Linux and Unix', 'Linux and Unix'),
        ('Programming and Computer Science', 'Programming and Computer Science'),
        ('Software Development', 'Software Development'),
        ('Web Development (Front)', 'Web Development (Front)'),
        ('Web Development (Back)', 'Web Development (Back)'),
        ('Mobile Development', 'Mobile Development'),
        ('Game Development', 'Game Development'),
        ('Algorithms and Data Structures', 'Algorithms and Data Structures'),
        ('Databases', 'Databases'),
        ('IDE / Text Editors', 'IDE / Text Editors'),
        ('Tutorial', 'Tutorial'),
        ('Opinion', 'Opinion'),
        ('Miscellaneous', 'Miscellaneous')
    ]
    field = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_post_detail', (), 
                {
                    'slug' :self.slug,
                })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @Romaan I get auth is not defined

Comment: @Romaan I have that imported now, but it says module object has no attribute User

Comment: @Romaan no module named django.contrib.models

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and then edit this line `author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)`

Comment: @Romaan Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: arcetina>>": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: You have progressed. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567667/cannot-assign-simplelazyobject-user-xxx-comment-user-must-be-a-mypro